# How to handle Error in XPath 2.0 expression Division by zero

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I had the below line of code which when I had been using xslt 1.0 gave no problem but in 2.0 it gave me the error

> XPath 2.0 expression Division by zero

```
<xsl:variable name="avg" select="round($sum div $count)"/>
```

Is there some way this can be handled as I tried searching various sites but was unable to find a answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable expression was taken partially from michael's solution

```
<xsl:variable name="avg" select="if ($count=0) then 0 else round($sum div $count)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$avg=0">
                'action here
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                'action here
            </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

And I think Im happy with the result

Comment: @Flynn1179 would you be able to suggest what to do then

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replicate the 1.0 behaviour, just make sure you are using double arithmetic rather than integer or decimal. You can achieve this by adding the type `as="xs:double"` to the declaration of variable $sum (variable $count will typically be declared as `xs:integer`). Declaring the types of your variables and parameters is basic code hygiene in XSLT 2.0.

If you want to use decimal arithmetic and recover from the error, e.g. by returning an empty sequence for this case, then use a conditional expression:

```
<xsl:variable name="avg"
     as="xs:decimal?" 
     select="if ($count=0) then () else round($sum div $count)"/>
```

Comment: you can't use as xs:decimal in a variable since it causes an xpath 2.0 error

Comment: It shouldn't cause an error. Perhaps you failed to declare the namespace? Otherwise, please tell us what error it causes.